# MDX Sum of Min on a set without using the set in the select

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have this situation:

Slot (dimension)
Customer(Dimension)
MinCounter(measure with MIN aggregation)
MaxCounter(measure with MAX aggregation)

I'd like to create a calculated member that is a Delta of counters (MaxCounter - MinCounter)
i used a simple formula:

[Measures].[MaxCounter] - [Measures].[MinCounter]

Obv it works when i use Slot dimension, because counters are relative to slot.

But I'd like to have the delta for every customer. Every customer have N slot
It means that to calculate delta i need to calculate delta for every slot of a customer and SUM all of them to have the delta of the customer. So i tried:

(SUM(([Slot].[Code].children, [Measures].[MaxCounter])) - SUM(([Slot].[Code].children, [Measures].[MinCounter])))

But it doesn't work.

When i try to make a pivot with customer as dimension and Delta like measure, i obtain wrong result. Delta it seems calculated like :

max counter between ALL THE SLOT of the customer

min counter between ALL THE SLOT of the customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be calculating that way because that is what you have asked it to so...

sum ( work out the max counter per slot ) -
sum ( work out the min counter per slot )

when you want to ask

sum ( per slot; max counter - min counter)

try creating a calculated member like

```
with member [Measures].[CounterDiff] as 
([Measures].[MaxCounter] - [Measures].[MinCounter])
```

and then using that in

```
sum([Slot].[Code].children, [Measures].[CounterDiff])
```

Comment: This is exactly what i've done yesterday!!! :) It's a bit slow using some dimension but u you gave me the confirmation this is a valid solution. Thanks